# BATCH Class - Inner Queries - Questions/Doubts

Tags: soql, batch, governorlimits, inner-join

I am doing few thing in Batch - and I was curious whether :

1. My SOQL Queries will work with 50000+ records ?
2. Will my SOQL's take too much time to execute and cause Time Out, etc ?

**SOQL**

```
SELECT id, StageName, (SELECT StageName,SystemModstamp,CreatedDate FROM OpportunityHistories order by CreatedDate asc), (SELECT id,Field1__c,CreatedDate FROM Tasks) FROM Opportunity WHERE ID IN :setoppID';
```

**where**

```
setOppID = select whatId from Task where What.Type='Opportunity'`
```

> NOTE: I DON'T WANNA CREATE MAP HERE --(some reason)

Comment: in batch database.querylocater can query 50 million records.. is you above query inside execute method?

Comment: No its not in Execute method , Its in "Start" method only

Comment: As @Ratan said above, you can work with a very large data set. Batch Apex will "break down" your query in chunks of 200 records, and process them 200 at at time. Also, I think that each chunk gets a full execution context. The limitation is that you can only reason on that chunk (ie: you cannot save state information from one chunk to another). Also, perhaps your 2 queries can be inlined into one. In other words, I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: I did tried inline them in one line- But "Task" entity doesn't support Inline Joins (got such error in Developer Console)

Comment: @mkorman   - Is there any specific Document which explains that Any no.of fetched i.e. 50k + records will work in Batch ?(where SOQL in START method)

Comment: Yes, Salesforce's own documentation on Batch Apex covers all of this information. Have you read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok related to your both questions

1 . We can query 50 million records in batch database.querylocater.

2 . If you are SOQL returning  more than 50,000 records. Since it is Asynchronous process. You will not face any timeout issue...

Asynchronous Callout Maximum timeout for a single continuation1 120 seconds

Refer this doc for Salesforce limitations

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/

Comment: Just a hypothetical question but what if we want to query more than 50 million records?

Comment: @javanoob you may require to contact salesforce in order to do that.. Do you really think any object record can be more than 50 million  in practical

Comment: As mentioned this is a hypothetical question. You can always expect crazy questions in a interview so just wanted to be prepared for that. Thanks!

Comment: The last sentence in the second statement is incorrect. You can still have a timeout in a query when running async apex.

Comment: @PepeFloyd pls feel free to edit my ans